# React hook form - do not revalidate on submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have 2 TextField with the following use case:
(note: fields are filled in with a scanner)

- enter any text in Part number en press ENTER (async validation runs for part number)
- enter any text in Batch number en press ENTER
  result: async validation happens for Batch number and because of the submit, it triggers the validation again on both fields.

Is there a way to turn off the revalidation on submit or a way to workaround it?
I will have the same issue with other forms and more fields

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uyggrr?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add an additional state to check the validate result:
`const [passed, setPassed] = React.useState({});` 
Everytime a validate function fires, it additionally sets its `passed` state to `true/false`. Once a field's `passed === true`, the `validate` attribute of the Controller gets passed:

```
    <Controller
      rules={{
      required: 'part number required',
      validate: () => passed['PartNumber'] || validate('PartNumber'),
      ...
    />
```

More detail at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rrcqpc?file=index.tsx

BTW, the werid error about hooks in your project is because of the uncorrect version of `react`, you can click refresh button aside of the **DEPENDENCIES**.

Comment: That works indeed, thank you. I was looking for a more elegant way provided by RHF to provide such common functionality. 
In Angular I have AsyncValidator so I was looking for something similar.